# Dynamically add images to article body

Tags: nodes, media, advertising

I want to add images to my article body field dynamically. Just like displaying advertisements in between the content.

Please help.

Comment: I would do this by writing some code. What've you got so far?

Comment: I am new to drupal. You can do because you might have sound knowledge of Drupal. –@adam_bear

Comment: @Gaurav You are expected to do the majority of the work on your own before you post questions. There's 1000 different ways to do it, and they all fit some narrow specific set of requirements. You need to narrow down the problem to something much more specific.

Comment: @echo No need for custom code, you could use the "SimpleAds" module (in D7), combined with a text filter, as explain in my answer to [this question](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/185).

Comment: @echo No need for custom code, you could use the "SimpleAds" module (in D7), combined with a text filter, as explained in my answer to [this question](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/185).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you need to edit the body field before rendering. There are 2 ways of doing this.

**1) Using the node template file**
In case of an article the template file would be node--article.tpl.php. Here is some sample code to edit the body field and include an ad after 4 paragraphs. The node--article.tpl.php file can be edited to make the following change.Here is the [quick reference](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) to theme pages in drupal.

```
 <?php
       $array = explode("<p>", render($content['body']));
       $array_size = sizeof($array);
       if($array_size < 5 ){
         $array[array_size-1] = $array[array_size-1]. $ad;
       }else{
         $array[4] = $array[4]. $ad;
       }
       $content['body'] = implode("", $array);
       print render($content['body']);
    ?>
```

instead of rendering the body using `<?php print render($content['body']); ?>`

**2) Using the hook_node_view.**

This node gets invoked before the node gets rendered. You can include your logic to edit the body field based on your requirement in this hook. I am assuming you have some idea of implementing hooks in your custom module. Refer to this [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) for more details of this hook.